# What is the protocol (GET, POST, etc) to be used that takes in form data to respond with other data?

Tags: javascript, http, http-protocols

I am working with a backend server and I am wondering what kind of request is ideal for processing and sending data based on an array that is being passed in the request.
Note this array does not have a specific size, and ideally I would have liked to pass this data in the body but I am confused since GET requests are used to fetch data and GET requests don't have a body.

What is the best practice in this case and what is the ideal request that should be used for such a case?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: All methods allow responses with data, so use the one that is semantically most appropriate - in your case I would suggest POST.